# What is the error in this org mode code?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Code :

```
#+OPTIONS: num:nil 
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil 
#+LATEX_HEADER: \pagenumbering{}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[right=1.5cm]{geometry} 
#+TITLE: 
#+BEGIN_FLUSHRIGHT

Manoj  

DOB: XX XX 1987 

PH 123456789

{{{date}}}

#+END_FLUSHRIGHT

* Past, Medical and Personal History  Patient complained of constipation since 2 months.  Patient is getting infrequent stools with frequency of * . Type of stool according to Bristol scale:  II  . Patient is getting pain during defecation. Patient noticed bleeding seperate from the stool .  Patient gets abdominal discomfort when constipated and feel better after defecation .
* History mnnmnm   Mucosal breaks more than 5 mm long, none of which extends between the tops of two mucosal folds suggested grade B reflux esophagitis by LA classification. 
* Examination 
- jhj 
- hjhj 
- jkjk  
* Investigations    hjhjComplete blood count, s creatinine, Serum sodium and pottasi

* Rx

1. abc  20 mg 1 tab  20 minutes before breakfast once daily 

2. cde  20 mg  20 minutes before breakfast once daily (1-0-0-0)  x
```

Error:-

```
    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable Pas)
  eval(Pas nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

Intermittently it exports to pdf through latex correctly, but mostly fails.

Details 
Windows 7
Emacs GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32)
Org Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10
Kindly help

Comment: Well, before it exports to PDF, it must create a TeX source. Can you also post that? It's really strange that it calls `eval` even though you have no Babel code blocks here... Maybe it's related somehow to `{{{date}}}`, though I wouldn't know.

Comment: The screen does not proceed to usual export option. No question of tex source

Comment: @wvxvw Removing {{{date}}} does not help

Comment: Are you sure you are pressing `C-c C-e` and not `C-x C-e`? First is normally bound to `org-export-dispatch` while second is bound to `eval-last-sexp` (which the exception seem to be coming from).

Comment: Will check and let you know. Thanks for feedback

Comment: That’s correct. C-x c-e by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, if I use lower case it works.

## +begin_flushright

Manoj

DOB: XX XX 1987

PH 123456789

{{{date}}}

## +end_flushright

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is right, in lower case it works.

You can read [Special-blocks-in-LaTeX-export](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-blocks-in-LaTeX-export.html#Special-blocks-in-LaTeX-export) to understand why.

In few words, your org-mode code

```
#+BEGIN_FLUSHRIGHT
  ...some text...
#+END_FLUSHRIGHT
```

was exported as the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{FLUSHRIGHT}
  ...some text...
\end{FLUSHRIGHT}
```

However, LaTeX expects a lower case environment name:

```
\begin{flushright}
  ...some text...
\end{flushright}
```

hence the right org-mode code is:

```
#+BEGIN_flushright
  ...some text...
#+END_flushright
```

---

Another example that uses the *quoting* package and forwards an option value to the exported LaTeX environment is:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{quoting}

...

#+ATTR_LATEX: :options [font=itshape]
#+BEGIN_quoting
   ...some text...
#+END_quoting
```

It is exported as the following LaTeX code:

```
\usepackage{quoting}
...
\begin{quoting}[font=itshape]
   ...some text...
\end{quoting}
```

Its effect is to use *italic* fonts for quoted text.